# Video file not playing after downloading using php

Tags: php

I use the script below to download a video, but the video file does not play after downloading to my pc, it's having a glitch when i try to play it, can any help me out.

My code below

```
<?php

$name = 'APM1M10VLOUO07C9.mp4';

header("Content-type: application/mp4");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$name);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($name);
exit;


?>
```

Comment: Is the size correct when downloaded? Also depending on browser I think `mp4` header can have the browser play it, `application/octet-stream` might be preferred.

Comment: Yes the file size of the video is correct when downloaded. i tried the 'application/octet-stream' but still giving me the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use

```
header("Content-type: video/mp4");
```